# Hibernate Entity Join by custom field

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities - User & Role as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class UserObj implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private long userId;

    @Column(name = "USER_NM")
    private String userNm;

    @Column(name = "USER_EMAIL")
    private String userEmail;

    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private String roleId;

    ---getter setter----
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE")
public class RoleObj implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private long roleId;

    @Column(name = "ROLE_NM")
    private String roleNm;

    @Column(name = "ROLE_DESC")
    private String roleDesc;

    ---getter setter----
}
```

User table will have role-id from Role table.

While querying entity (using hibernate), How to get role_nm in user object (not as a role object), but only role_nm string field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a field in UserObj class and use the [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html) annotation. Like this:

```
@Fomula( "( SELECT r.role_nm FROM role r WHERE r.role_id = role_id )" )
private String roleNm;
```

Comment: @Formula annotation solved my problem. I am able to add new field in entity & assign custom query to it.

Answer (score -1):

You can add Role Object to User Entity with ManyToOne relationship and eager fetch type. This way whenever you fetch a user object, you will fetch role object with user.

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
  private RoleObj roleObj;
```

After that you can get roleNm of a user like this

```
user.getRoleObj().getRoleNm()
```

Comment: not practical to get the whole object IMHO..